# How do I find circuit board layouts (footprints/packages) for embedded processors?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, packages

I am seeking layouts for mobile processors like the ones in phones. I am not sure which processor I will use yet but I am just trying to get a general idea of where to find these layouts.

Comment: In datasheets. There are some typical footprints (mostly BGA packages) but the specifics of the footprints vary. Look up 0.5mm bga.

Comment: The datasheets. Decide which processor you want to use and then look up the datasheet to find the package style and recommended footprint.

Comment: @PeterSmith I think you beat me by half a second =P

Comment: You also want to check the application notes. Many vendors put useful information there, like decoupling or quarz layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Eagle, sometimes the component distributor, Newark Electronics aka Element14, will have a ULP for generating a library part on the component's listing page. That's nice when its available.

But at any rate, you should get used to making your own library of parts, because sooner or later you are going to want to use something that's not available.

Comment: Yeah, and often enough you spend more time searching for a part than in making it yourself.

Comment: Okay thanks for the information. Do you know how I can find the information so I can make my own package if I can't download one. Like a basic document telling the dimensions and locations for each wire for a circuit board layout?

Comment: Depends on your EDA tool. For Eagle there are countless YouTube videos. I suspect so for KiCAD and others as well. It's not that difficult in general once you get the hang of it.

Comment: @Adamisme:  Most good datasheets will either have a drawing with dimensions or a reference to another document  with that information so that you can draw your own footprints.  Pinout is, of course, in the datasheet as well.